# Executing command line command from Python

Tags: windows, command-line, subprocess

I know people have addressed things similar to this, but I am still confused.

I want to execute a command "Inventory.bat rap.t00z.awp236pgrbf00.grib2 rap.t00z.awp236pgrbf00 LoLa 25 48 33 -122 -83" in windows command line using Python.

My current Python script is:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['Inventory.bat', 'rap.t00z.awp236pgrbf00.grib2 rap.t00z.awp236pgrbf00', 'LoLa', '25', '48', '33', '-122', '-83'])
```

This doesn't work when executed by Python. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Windows, `.bat` files are executed by the `cmd` shell. To use the shell you must include the `shell=True` option to the `subprocess` functions.

```
subprocess.check_output(['Inventory.bat', 'rap.t00z.awp236pgrbf00.grib2 rap.t00z.awp236pgrbf00', 'LoLa', '25', '48', '33', '-122', '-83'], shell=True)
```

Comment: @Waterguy not sure, `subprocess` is supposed to wait until the command is finished before it returns. Possibly the cmd shell itself is starting something without waiting for it, you can check by putting an `echo` at the end of your batch file. If so you'd need to ask on SuperUser or elsewhere.